# How to use time_to_sec in doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I make an application using symfony2, but got stuck at one point. In my previous application I used MySQL and PHP5. But now I'm making the same application in symfony2. I don't know how to use time_to_sec function in doctrine. Here is my code.

```
public function hitsPerTimeAction($customer=null, $token=null, $cdn, $domain, $dateFrom, $dateTo, $tb, $frequency, $db) { 
      $data=array(); 
      if($db == "DB1"){ 
          $rds = "rds1"; 
      }else{ 
          $rds = "rds2"; 
      } 
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager($rds); 
      if($frequency == "1 hour"){ 
          $lesVolumes = $em->createQuery("select concat(v.date,'',sec_to_time(time_to_sec(concat(v.date,' ',v.time))time_to_sec(concat(v.date,' ',v.time))%(60*60))) 
                  as 'atime',sum(v.count) as 'volume' from AppBundle:Hitspt$tb v where v.domain like'%$domain%' and 
                  v.date between '$date From' and '$dateTo' and v.cdn='$cdn' group by atime"); 
          $results = $lesVolumes->getArrayResult();

          $volume =array();
          $time = array();
          $i=0;
          foreach($results as $result){
                $volume[$i]=$result["volume"];
                //$time[$i]=$result["time"].' - '.$result["date"];
                $time[$i]=$result["atime"];
                $i++;
          }
          $response= new JsonResponse(array("volume" => $volume, "time" => $time));
          $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
          return $response;
     }
}
```

Comment: could be useful to read the full code of the Extension https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/src/Query/Mysql/TimeToSec.php

Comment: and here is how to work with dates in doctrine could be useful too http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html